# Convolution - Calculating a Neighbour Element Index for a Vectorised Image

Tags: java, image-processing, vector, indexing, convolution

Assume the following matrix acts as both an image and a kernel in a matrix convolution operation:

```
0 1 2  
3 4 5  
6 7 8
```

To calculate the neighbour pixel index you would use the following formula:

```
neighbourColumn = imageColumn + (maskColumn - centerMaskColumn);
neighbourRow = imageRow + (maskRow - centerMaskRow);
```

Thus the output of convolution would be:

```
output1 = {0,1,3,4} x {4,5,7,8} = 58
output2 = {0,1,2,3,4,5} x {3,4,5,6,7,8} = 100 
output2 = {1,2,4,5} x {3,4,6,7} = 70
output3 = {0,1,3,4,6,7} x {1,2,4,5,7,8} = 132
output4 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} x {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} = 204
output5 = {1,2,4,5,7,8} x {0,1,3,4,6,7} = 132
output6 = {3,4,6,7} x {1,2,4,5} = 70
output7 = {3,4,5,6,7,8} x {0,1,2,3,4,5} = 100
output8 = {4,5,7,8} x {0,1,3,4} = 58
```

Thus the output matrix would be:

```
58  100 70
132 204 132
70  100 58
```

Now assume the matrix is flattened to give the following vector:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

This vector now acts as an image and a kernel in a vector convolution operation for which the ouput should be:

```
58 100 70 132 204 132 70 100 58
```

Given the code below how do you calculate the neighbour element index for the vector such that it corresponds with the same neighbour element in the matrix?

```
public int[] convolve(int[] image, int[] kernel)
{       
  int imageValue; 
  int kernelValue;
  int outputValue;
  int[] outputImage = new int[image.length()];

  // loop through image
  for(int i = 0; i < image.length(); i++)
  {      
    outputValue = 0;

    // loop through kernel
    for(int j = 0; j < kernel.length(); j++)
    {
      neighbour = ?;

      // discard out of bound neighbours 
      if (neighbour >= 0 && neighbour < imageSize)
      {
        imageValue = image[neighbour];
        kernelValue = kernel[j];          
        outputValue += imageValue * kernelValue;
      }
    }

    outputImage[i] = outputValue;
  }        

  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neighbour index is computed by offsetting the original pixel index by the difference between the index of the current element and half the size of the matrix. For example, to compute the column index:

```
int neighbourCol = imageCol + col - (size / 2);
```

I put a working demo [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/90143c942847a1dd08fa), trying to keep the whole convolution algorithm as readable as possible:

```
int[] dstImage = new int[srcImage.width() * srcImage.height()];

srcImage.forEachElement((image, imageCol, imageRow) -> {
  Pixel pixel = new Pixel();
  forEachElement((filter, col, row) -> {
    int neighbourCol = imageCol + col - (size / 2);
    int neighbourRow = imageRow + row - (size / 2);
    if (srcImage.hasElementAt(neighbourCol, neighbourRow)) {
      int color = srcImage.at(neighbourCol, neighbourRow);
      int weight = filter.at(col, row);
      pixel.addWeightedColor(color, weight);
    }
  });

  dstImage[(imageRow * srcImage.width() + imageCol)] = pixel.rgb();
});
```

Comment: I edited my post to include some sample code, could you explain what you mean in relation to it, thanks :)

Comment: So what are your input and outputs? int[][] for the image and int[] for the kernel?

Comment: I have updated my post to show the input and expected output,   in this case the method can not accept a 2d image or a 2d kernel, however the code can be ammended to accept a width and/or height parameter. i.e. the results of the output element values of vector convolution must be the same as output values of matrix convolution.

Comment: You can use the provided code to convert 2D to array and leave the convolute function as is

Comment: In my solution I should not convert from 2D to 1D so i need the 1d neighbour index to match that of it's 2d representation

Comment: So what? Provided the convolute function works (I'm not entirely sure), we don't want to touch it. So just convert from 2D to array when bridging is needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84597/discussion-between-5had3sofqu4rtz-and-raffaele).

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with 2D images, you will have to retain some information about the images, in addition the the plain 1D pixel array. Particularly, you at least need the *width* of the image (and the mask) in order to find out which indices in the 1D array correspond to which indices in the original 2D image. And as already pointed out by [Raffaele in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31705010/3182664), there are general rules for the conversions between these ("virtual") 2D coordinates and 1D coordinates in such a pixel array:

```
int pixelX = ...;
int pixelY = ...;
int index = pixelX + pixelY * imageSizeX;
```

Based on this, you can do your convolution simply on a 2D image. The limits for the pixels that you may access may easily be checked. The loops are simple 2D loops over the image and the mask. It all boils down to the point where you access the 1D data with the 2D coordinates, as described above.

Here is an example. It applies a Sobel filter to the input image. (There may still be something odd with the pixel values, but the convolution itself and the index computations should be right)

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ConvolutionWithArrays1D
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final BufferedImage image = 
            asGrayscaleImage(ImageIO.read(new File("lena512color.png")));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI(image);
            }
        });

    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(BufferedImage image0)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));


        f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image0)));

        BufferedImage image1 = compute(image0);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image1)));


        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static BufferedImage asGrayscaleImage(BufferedImage image)
    {
        BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        Graphics2D g = gray.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return gray;
    }

    private static int[] obtainGrayscaleIntArray(BufferedImage image)
    {
        BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        Graphics2D g = gray.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        DataBuffer dataBuffer = gray.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
        DataBufferByte dataBufferByte = (DataBufferByte)dataBuffer;
        byte data[] = dataBufferByte.getData();
        int result[] = new int[data.length];
        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = data[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static BufferedImage createImageFromGrayscaleIntArray(
        int array[], int imageSizeX, int imageSizeY)
    {
        BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(
            imageSizeX, imageSizeY, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        DataBuffer dataBuffer = gray.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
        DataBufferByte dataBufferByte = (DataBufferByte)dataBuffer;
        byte data[] = dataBufferByte.getData();
        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (byte)array[i];
        }
        return gray;
    }

    private static BufferedImage compute(BufferedImage image)
    {
        int imagePixels[] = obtainGrayscaleIntArray(image);
        int mask[] = 
        {
             1,0,-1,
             2,0,-2,
             1,0,-1,
        };
        int outputPixels[] = 
            Convolution.filter(imagePixels, image.getWidth(), mask, 3);
        return createImageFromGrayscaleIntArray(
            outputPixels, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

    }

}


class Convolution
{
    public static final int[] filter(
        final int[] image, int imageSizeX,
        final int[] mask, int maskSizeX)
    {
        int imageSizeY = image.length / imageSizeX;
        int maskSizeY = mask.length / maskSizeX;
        int output[] = new int[image.length];
        for (int y=0; y<imageSizeY; y++)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<imageSizeX; x++)
            {
                int outputPixelValue = 0;
                for (int my=0; my< maskSizeY; my++)
                {
                    for (int mx=0; mx< maskSizeX; mx++)
                    {
                        int neighborX = x + mx -maskSizeX / 2;
                        int neighborY = y + my -maskSizeY / 2;

                        if (neighborX >= 0 && neighborX < imageSizeX &&
                            neighborY >= 0 && neighborY < imageSizeY)
                        {
                            int imageIndex = 
                                neighborX + neighborY * imageSizeX;
                            int maskIndex = mx + my * maskSizeX;

                            int imagePixelValue = image[imageIndex];
                            int maskPixelValue = mask[maskIndex];
                            outputPixelValue += 
                                imagePixelValue * maskPixelValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                outputPixelValue = truncate(outputPixelValue);

                int outputIndex = x + y * imageSizeX;
                output[outputIndex] = outputPixelValue;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    private static final int truncate(final int pixelValue)
    {
        return Math.min(255, Math.max(0, pixelValue));
    }
}
```